# Android log.i is lost

Tags: android

I need to print some app informations when something goes wrong. I want these messages to be sent with the stack traces that users send do report problems. I'm trying to use `Log` class to do this.

I have a `listview` with items and after an users picks on one of those items, I start a new activity.
Right before this new activity start I want to log a message,

Imagine this:

```
        Log.i("Delete success: ", "File deleted");
        System.out.println("Arrived here");
        query.close();
        startActivity(i);
```

If I use the above code, at the console, the `System.out.println("Arrived here");` is displayed but not the `log.i`. If I do this code:

```
        System.out.println("Going to log???");
        Log.i("Delete success: ", "File deleted");
        System.out.println("Arrived here");
        query.close();
        startActivity(i);
```

Now, all the messages are displayed at the console.

Why is this happening? Is this happening because `log.i` has some overhead and the new activity is started before the `log.i` as "time" to print?

Comment: use `log.i` instead of `System.out.println("")` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes. I know. But `log.i` is only displaying the message if a System.out.println("") is before

Comment: Did you have any logcat filters active in the console view during the first experiment that were not active during the second?

Comment: @TedHopp No. It's exactly the same in both experiment. logcat filter is set to info

Comment: Did you try to print with `log.e` just to see if it's a level problem?

Comment: @Zoltán Yes. I've tried `log.e`, log.i` and `log.d` and the result is always the same